# Check unique number

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check JMBG (unique number of citizenship in my country). It has 13 numbers and is calculated by the following code. The function returns that my JMBG is wrong. Perhaps somewhere in code I did wrong calculations.

Here is an example. Real life JMBG is 0805988212987 and this function returns wrong month.

```
Function Check_JMBG(JMBG As String) As String

' Function returns message with notification of JMBG validation
' JMBG has 13 numbers and can be treated like this when checking it DD.MM.GGG.OO.BBB.K
' Details of JMBG (unique citizenship number in my country, is 13 by the way):

'DD - day of birth
'MM - manth of birth
'GGG - last 3 numbers of year of birth, starting from (1)899. year
'OO - municipality birth code
'BBB - serial number of birth person. Man from 001-499, woman from 501-999
'K - control number, modulo 11

Dim size As Integer, sum As Integer
Dim number(1 To 13) As Integer
Dim day As Integer, manth As Integer, year As String

size = Len(JMBG)
day = Int(Left(JMBG, 2))
manth = Int(Mid$(JMBG, 3, 2))
year = Mid$(JMBG, 5, 3)

' Size check
If (size <> 13) Then
  Check_JMBG = "ERR: size of JMBG is not 13!"
End If

'Date check
If day < 1 Then
  Check_JMBG = "ERR: date entered is wrong!"
  Exit Function
End If

'Manth check and date inside manth
Select Case manth
  Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
    If day > 31 Then
      Check_JMBG = "ERR: date number is wrong!"
      Exit Function
    End If
  Case 4, 6, 9, 11
    If day > 30 Then
      Check_JMBG = "ERR: data number is wrong!"
      Exit Function
    End If
  Case 2
    If ((year Mod 4 = 0) And day > 29) Or _
       ((year Mod 4 <> 0) And day > 28) Then
      Check_JMBG = "ERR: date number is wrong!"
      Exit Function
    End If
  Case Else
    Check_JMBG = "ERR: manth number is wrong!"
    Exit Function
End Select

'Check year: from 1899 till today
If (year > Right(str(Year(Now)), 3)) And (year < "899") Then
  Check_JMBG = "ERR: year number is wrong!"
  Exit Function
End If

'Control number check
For i = 1 To 13
  number(i) = Int(Mid$(JMBG, i, 1))
Next i

sum = number(13) + number(1) * 7 + number(2) * 6
sum = sum + number(3) * 5 + number(4) * 4
sum = sum + number(5) * 3 + number(6) * 2
sum = sum + number(7) * 7 + number(8) * 6
sum = sum + number(9) * 5 + number(10) * 4
sum = sum + number(11) * 3 + number(12) * 2

If (sum Mod 11) <> 0 Then
  Check_JMBG = "ERR: wrong control number!"
Else
  Check_JMBG = "JMBG is correct"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine for the month. I got a compile error, as you use the same name for the variable `year` and the VBA function - once I replaced it with `strYear` this also works. Can you provide an example where it does not work and the month is causing a problem?

Comment: 0805988212987 ...check this one...

Comment: Show us how you called the function, your expected output for month, and your actual output for month.

Comment: In excel cell A1 is entered : 0805988212987. Then in B1 an example I call =Check_JMBG(A1)

Comment: Then Excel has probably interpreted your number as a `Double` and dropped the leading `0` before converting to a `String` in the function call. Prefix the number with a single quote '0805988212987.

Comment: I think that somewhere in code, if and for loops has been made mistake and I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and it works fine for the month. I got a compile error, as you use the same name for the variable year and the VBA function - once I replaced it with strYear this also works.

Take a look at the refactored code below and see if this fixes your problem:

```
Function Check_JMBG(JMBG As String) As String
    If (Len(JMBG) <> 13) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERR: Length of JMBG is not 13!"
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(JMBG) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERR: JMBG contains non-numerical characters"
    ElseIf Not fctBlnCheckDate(JMBG) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERR: Wrong date entered!"
    ElseIf fctBlnCheckSum(JMBG) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERR: Wrong checksum!"
    Else
        Check_JMBG = "JMBG is correct"
    End If
End Function

Private Function fctBlnCheckDate(JMBG As String) As Boolean
    Dim intDay As Integer, intMonth As Integer, intYear As Integer
    Dim datCheck As Date

    intDay = Int(Left(JMBG, 2))
    intMonth = Int(Mid$(JMBG, 3, 2))
    intYear = Int(Mid$(JMBG, 5, 3)) + 1000

    datCheck = DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay)

    fctBlnCheckDate = _
        (year(datCheck) = intYear) And _
        (Month(datCheck) = intMonth) And _
        (day(datCheck) = intDay)

End Function

Private Function fctBlnCheckSum(JMBG As String) As Boolean
    Dim intCheckSum As Integer, i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 13
        intCheckSum = intCheckSum + Int(Mid$(JMBG, i, 1)) * (IIf(i < 7, 8, 14) - i)
    Next 
    fctBlnCheckSum = (intCheckSum Mod 11) <> 0 
End Function
```

Comment: Re type it again, you have mistakes, you have forgot to copy some parts.

Comment: I don't think so! Give it a try! ;-)

Comment: Last part : intCheckSum = intCheckSum + Int(Mid$(JMBG, i, 1)) * (IIf(i  0

Comment: ah! had to replace `<` with `&lt;` in the pasted code. should work now!

Comment: Just realized there where some more `<` in the code and not properly displayed. Now it's all fixed! Does work now?

Comment: Good! Though I used the (refactored) checksum method that you used, not the one mentioned in the other answer (that somehow got lost). So make sure, this is the right one!

Comment: Listen can you check this one...check sum is done by this form JMBG: ABCDEFHHIJKLM where

   M = 11 - ( 7*(A+G) + 6*(B+H) + 5*(C+I) + 4*(D+J) + 3*(E+K) + 2*(F+L) ) % 11  ...and if above formula is correct than it is OK, else it is not.

Comment: Look, this is not freecoder.com! You have been given a lot of helpful advice and code - give it a try yourself. And if you get stuck, come back and ask for help, but don't expect all the work being done for you!

Comment: Just wanted you to check is this correct with my last comment formula and implement it in your solution above.                             For i = 1 To 13
  number(i) = Int(Mid$(JMBG, i, 1))
Next i
sum = number(13) + number(1) * 7 + number(2) * 6
sum = zbir + number(3) * 5 + number(4) * 4
sum = zbir + number(5) * 3 + number(6) * 2
sum = zbir + number(7) * 7 + number(8) * 6
sum = zbir + number(9) * 5 + number(10) * 4
sum = zbir + number(11) * 3 + number(12) * 2
If (sum Mod 11) <> 0 Then
  Check_JMBG = "ERR: wrong checksum!"
Else
  Check_JMBG = "JMBG correct"
End If

Comment: the code you just posted is the one from your original question (only that you still have zbir in there) - that's what my code also does, just in a loop. so it should be fine.

Comment: That's what I just wanted. I found this solution for checksum with M on internet and I wanted to check it with you to see is there any major differenc, nothing special. Thanks again, anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Your function is expecting a string, and you are passing a number. As you do not exit the function after the size check, you are not picking up the error.

`=Check_JMBG(805988212987)` gives the error **manth is wrong**

`=Check_JMBG("0805988212987")` gives message **JMBG is correct**

[image: formatting makes a difference]

note the green triangle in the upper left of cell A1... That means I have entered the number as text by including a `'` (single quote) beefore the number.

You can alter your test slightly to cover the missing zeros. - right after you get the size, and before you extract the day,month and year, put this code:

```
If (size <> 13) Then
    'add leading zeros
    JMBG = String(13 - size, "0") & JMBG
End If
```

---

Full code:

```
Function Check_JMBG(JMBG As String) As String

' Function returns message with notification of JMBG validation
' JMBG has 13 numbers and can be treated like this when checking it DD.MM.GGG.OO.BBB.K
' Details of JMBG (unique citizenship number in my country, is 13 by the way):

'DD - day of birth
'MM - manth of birth
'GGG - last 3 numbers of strYear of brith, starting from (1)899. strYear
'OO - municipality birth code
'BBB - serial number of birth person. Man from 001-499, woman from 501-999
'K - control number, modulo 11

Dim size As Integer, sum As Integer
Dim number(1 To 13) As Integer
Dim day As Integer, manth As Integer, strYear As String

size = Len(JMBG)

' Size check
If (size <> 13) Then
  JMBG = String(13 - size, "0") & JMBG
End If

day = Int(Left(JMBG, 2))
manth = Int(Mid$(JMBG, 3, 2))
strYear = Mid$(JMBG, 5, 3)

'Date check
If day < 1 Then
  Check_JMBG = "ERR: date entered is wrong!"
  Exit Function
End If

'Manth check and date inside manth
Select Case manth
  Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
    If day > 31 Then
      Check_JMBG = "ERR: date number is wrong!"
      Exit Function
    End If
  Case 4, 6, 9, 11
    If day > 30 Then
      Check_JMBG = "ERR: data number is wrong!"
      Exit Function
    End If
  Case 2
    If ((strYear Mod 4 = 0) And day > 29) Or _
       ((strYear Mod 4 <> 0) And day > 28) Then
      Check_JMBG = "ERR: date number is wrong!"
      Exit Function
    End If
  Case Else
    Check_JMBG = "ERR: month number is wrong!"
    Exit Function
End Select

'Check strYear: from 1899 till today
If (strYear > Right(str(Year(Now)), 3)) And (strYear < "899") Then
  Check_JMBG = "ERR: strYear number is wrong!"
  Exit Function
End If

'Control number check
For i = 1 To 13
  number(i) = Int(Mid$(JMBG, i, 1))
Next i

sum = number(13) + number(1) * 7 + number(2) * 6
sum = sum + number(3) * 5 + number(4) * 4
sum = sum + number(5) * 3 + number(6) * 2
sum = sum + number(7) * 7 + number(8) * 6
sum = sum + number(9) * 5 + number(10) * 4
sum = sum + number(11) * 3 + number(12) * 2

If (sum Mod 11) <> 0 Then
  Check_JMBG = "ERR: wrong control number!"
Else
  Check_JMBG = "JMBG is correct"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: I know all of that. My excel cells are set as text. Can you re type my code and upload it above to see it in full size.